# Codeigniter organizing controllers structure

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Let's take for example a small social network site. One of modules are also Quizzes. Quizzes module have the following sections:

```
-Create quize
-Edit quize
-Quize view
-Browse quizes
-Send quize to friend
```

I am wondering what would be the best way in this case. One of option is to create for each module section another controller.

```
controllers/create_quize.php
controllers/edit_quize.php
controllers/quize_view.php
controllers/browse_quizes.php
controllers/send_quize.php
```

Another way would be to create single controller for entire module with many functions. None of options are ok. In first way, this could mean to have more than 30 controllers in my controllers folder (having in mind that quizess is just one of many modules). Second option is not ok because a single file will have many functions and won't be easily scanned to developer.

I was also thinking to create many controllers, but organizing them into subfolders. Anyway condeigniter doesn't have this option without modification.

Tnx!

Comment: tnx for warning. To be honest, I didn't even know about this option. Now I know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a single controller for your quizzes. Your `quiz` controller might look like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Quiz extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function index()
    {
        // Index page. List all quizzes here, perhaps as an replacement to /browse
        // /quiz/
    }


    function create()
    {
        // Create a new quiz
        // /quiz/create
    }


    function edit($quiz_id)
    {
        // Edit quiz with $quiz_id
        // /quiz/edit/1
    }


    function browse()
    {
        // Index page. List all quizzes here, perhaps
        // /quiz/browse
    }


    function send($quiz_id)
    {
        // Send/share page
        // /quiz/send/1
    }

}
```

CodeIgniter is a Model-view-controller framework. You may want to review how it's structured: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/